# Custom font loading from icomoon

Tags: css, fonts, icons

I am using icomoon to create a custom font but i can not get it to load. I have checked it using font book at it seems to be ok there but I am having trouble loading it.

```html
@font-face {
  font-family: 'icomoon';
  src: url('icomoon.eot');
  src: url('icomoon.eot#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('dilatefonts/icomoon.ttf') format('truetype'), url('icomoon.woff') format('woff'), url('icomoon.svg') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28g5Z.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3aLI.png)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your style.css and font are in the same folder. 
Please try to remove **dilatefonts** from font path. Example below -

```
  @font-face {
  font-family: 'icomoon';
  src: url('icomoon.eot');
  src: url('icomoon.eot#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('dilatefonts/icomoon.ttf') format('truetype'), url('icomoon.woff') format('woff'), url('icomoon.svg') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: Hi Jahirul thanks for your response. I have copied in your code and moved the style.scss (now called dstyle.scss) into the scss folder but i'm still getting no luck. I'll update the question with how it now looks - any more help would be really well received!